# Why Rsyslog Server do not create file into a directory when receiving data?

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I used the folliwing straitforward simple documentation to deploy a remote rsyslog server
https://www.tecmint.com/install-rsyslog-centralized-logging-in-centos-ubuntu/

I have the following minimalist rsyslog configuration (/etc/rsyslog.conf) on a remote `serverA`, The rest of the configuration is the default /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file on CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

```
#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

### Rules for processing the Remote Logs
$template RemoteLogs,"/data/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
& ~
```

It allows incoming messages on port 514 (either by UPD or TCP) to be written into a file named after the programname issuing these data
and into a directory named after the hostname sending the data

My issue is that when I send data (programname = dump.program) from a client host called clientB to my remote syslog serverA,
the directorory /data/rsyslog/clientB is not created neither the file /data/rsyslog/clientB/dump.program.log

A tcpdump on `serverA` clearly shows that data a coming from `clientB`

> $ sudo tcpdump -A dst serverA | grep clientB

```
<134>Oct 25 10:09:28 clientB cassandra-access: {"I-logdate":"2021-10-22 14:24:11,715","I-level":"INFO","I-process":"SocketServer","I-brokerid":"1020787186","message":"Failed authentication with 10.227.214.2/10.227.214.2 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)","I-MessageID":"fykfvghjw6qn2fh1","I-@Ip":"10.207.87.186","I-NomPF":"KAFKA","I-NomVM":"hwi31dev02kfkzbomomtmo02","I-PathTrace":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","I-RoleVM":"MOM","I-TypePF":"DEV","I-TypeTrace":"KAFKA","I-TypeVM":"MO","I-VersionOS":"CentOS release 6.10 (Final)","I-VersionSocle":"601-029","fi
10:09:28.463674 IP clientB.42330 > hwi31dev01danazboapplitbo02.shell: Flags [.], seq 711445:712893, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3499524066 ecr 3499512980], length 1448
<134>Oct 25 10:09:28 clientB cassandra-access: {"I-logdate":"2021-10-22 14:24:12,909","I-level":"INFO","I-process":"SocketServer","I-brokerid":"1020787186","message":"Failed authentication with 10.227.214.2/10.227.214.2 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)","I-MessageID":"fykfvghjw6qn2fh2","I-@Ip":"10.207.87.186","I-NomPF":"KAFKA","I-NomVM":"hwi31dev02kfkzbomomtmo02","I-PathTrace":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","I-RoleVM":"MOM","I-TypePF":"DEV","I-TypeTrace":"KAFKA","I-TypeVM":"MO","I-VersionOS":"CentOS release 6.10 (Final)","I-VersionSocle":"601-029","file":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","pfname":"KAFKA"}
<134>Oct 25 10:09:28 clientB cassandra-access: {"I-logdate":"2021-10-22 14:24:13,655","I-level":"INFO","I-process":"SocketServer","I-brokerid":"1020787186","message":"Failed authentication with 10.227.214.2/10.227.214.2 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)","I-MessageID":"fykfvghjw6qn2fh3","I-@Ip":"10.207.87.186","I-NomPF":"KAFKA","I-NomVM":"hwi31dev02kfkzbomomtmo02","I-PathTrace":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","I-RoleVM":"MOM","I-TypePF":"DEV","I-TypeTrace":"KAFKA","I-TypeVM":"MO","I-VersionOS":"CentOS release 6.10 (Final)","I-VersionSocle":"601-029","file":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","pfname":"KAFKA"}
<134>Oct 25 10:09:28 clientB cassandra-access: {"
10:09:28.463684 IP clientB > hwi31dev01danazboapplitbo02.shell: Flags [P.], seq 712893:714150, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3499524067 ecr 3499512981], length 1257
<134>Oct 25 10:09:28 clientB cassandra-access: {"I-logdate":"2021-10-22 14:24:15,077","I-level":"INFO","I-process":"SocketServer","I-brokerid":"1020787186","message":"Failed authentication with 10.227.214.2/10.227.214.2 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)","I-MessageID":"fykfvghjw6qn2fh5","I-@Ip":"10.207.87.186","I-NomPF":"KAFKA","I-NomVM":"hwi31dev02kfkzbomomtmo02","I-PathTrace":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","I-RoleVM":"MOM","I-TypePF":"DEV","I-TypeTrace":"KAFKA","I-TypeVM":"MO","I-VersionOS":"CentOS release 6.10 (Final)","I-VersionSocle":"601-029","file":"/hawai/logs/kafka/server.log","pfname":"KAFKA"}
```

My understanding therefore is that data are successfuly handle by the rsyslog service on `serverA`, so why are'nt they written down on `/data/rsyslog/clientB/dump.program.log` ?

> rsyslogd -version

```
rsyslogd 5.8.10, compiled with:
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
```

Am I missing something on the server ?

Is it a writting permissions issue ?

I am lost, any help are welcome

Comment: Have you created the files that you want to log to yourself? Because rsyslog doesn't "automatically" create files. If they're missing, rsyslog writes to the file handle you defined but which actually doesn't even exist.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, you'd have to test it. But if I remember it correctly, the `omfile` module should create a log file if it doesnt exist. 
e.g. `action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/someFile.log")`